# Append data into another table with the same columns but different order

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert

I am using SQL Server, and I want to write a query to append data from Table 1 into Table 2, which already has some data in it.

This is what I am currently using, but this only works when the columns are exactly the same in the exact same order. My 2 tables have the same columns, but the order is different. There is 200+ columns so I do not want to manually reorder them or have to list them in the query.

```
INSERT INTO table2
    SELECT * FROM table1
```

This is one way I could do it, but is there a way to append data from table1 into table2 without having to specify each column?

```
INSERT INTO table2
    SELECT column1, column2 (in the order of table2 columns)
    FROM table1
```

Comment: No. What you are asking for is not possible. You should specify the columns in the insert as well.

Comment: `insert table2(col2,col1) select col1,col2 from table1` (`table2.col2` is the same as `table1.col1`)

Comment: Your #2 is potentially possible. Select list must contain **all** columns in `table2` *provided* `table2` doesn't have *calculated* columns like `identity`

Comment: Do you not want to do this manually because you don't want to type out 200+ columns or because you don't want 200+ columns listed in your query? I can think of a few ways around this.

Comment: Both. Is there a way to hide potions of a query? Like Select col1, col2,... From table1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A less tidy but potentially practical way to do this is by building with `exec`. `string_agg` is only available on 2017 though

```
declare @col_names nvarchar(max) = (
  select string_agg(column_name, ',')
  from information_schema.columns
  where table_name = N'table1'
)

exec ('insert into table2 (' + @col_names + ') select ' + @col_names + ' from table1')
```

for pre-sql server 2017 from comment:

```
declare @col_names nvarchar(max)
select @col_names = ISNULL(@col_names + ', [' + column_name + ']', '[' + column_name + ']')
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = @dest
```

Comment: I am using SSMS 17, but I am getting "string_agg is not a recognized" error. It looks like i need to use something called vNext?

Comment: SSMS version shouldn't matter, just the sql server version. Guessing you have an older version (check with `select @@version`). I made an edit with an alternative.

Comment: I did something similar using the query below. Is there any benefit to using what you wrote, specifically performance related ?  select @col_names = ISNULL(@col_names + ', [' + column_name + ']', '[' + column_name + ']')
from information_schema.columns

Comment: Nice, that looks pretty slick. As far as performance, I think it would be pretty trivial in this case. Looks like your way is better since it's simpler.

Comment: I actually came back to this for a utility I'm working on - used your suggestion for pre-2017, works great! Edited answer.

Comment: awesome, ill mark as answer. glad we found a simple solution. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Elaskanator's warning about listing out your column names explicitly. However, this method will work.

Create a view (vw_table1) on table1 that has the column order of table2. You will need to specify the proper column order in the view.

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM vw_table1
```

If you just need a comma-separated list of columns you can get that a number of different ways...

- Query table2 with the Results to Text specified and then replace all spaces with one comma and a spaces for readability.
- Query table2, Copy with Headers to Excel, save as CSV, and copy the first row from the resulting file.
- If you have RedGate, hit "Tab" after the "*" in SELECT * FROM table2 and it will list them out for you.

Comment: what is the added benefit of using a view instead of selecting directly from table1?

Comment: A view will allow you to re-order the columns in table1 to match the order of table2. So the explicit listing of all of the columns (which you only have to do once) is hidden in the view.

Answer (score 0):

**Never write `INSERT` statements lacking an explicit column list**, otherwise in the future if somebody reorders the columns (which in a way also happens when adding new columns in the middle of the table) everything will suddenly start breaking (hopefully, because you could end up inserting values that implicitly convert for a while, causing random failures later that will make your life hell).

If your primary concern is the sheer number of columns making it difficult to write the statement (are you saving data horizontally or something?), then use dynamic SQL to get going in the proper direction:

```
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(255) = N'MyBigassTable'--SET ME
DECLARE @ColumnList NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL--build column list string
SELECT @ColumnList = ISNULL(@ColumnList + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(9) + ',', CHAR(9) + ' ') + QUOTENAME(C.name)
FROM--ordering is guaranteed to match with the current table definition, presumably from clustered index on the sys.columns table?
    sys.tables AS T
    INNER JOIN sys.columns AS C ON
        C.object_id = T.object_id
        AND C.is_identity = 0--https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql
        AND C.is_computed = 0--https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table
WHERE T.name = @TableName--beware if you have multiple schemas with the same table name
--form the insert statement
DECLARE @InsertQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) =
    N'INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
    +'(' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
    + @ColumnList + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
    + ')' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
    + 'SELECT' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
    + @ColumnList
--output results, handling maximum print size limitation
DECLARE @i INT = 1, @Step INT = 4000
WHILE @i < LEN(@InsertQuery) BEGIN
    PRINT SUBSTRING(@InsertQuery, @i, @Step)--you will have to manually fix newlines created by PRINT batches
    SET @i += @Step
END
```

Sample result

```
INSERT INTO [MyBigassTable]
(
     [ID]
    ,[Name]
    ...
)
SELECT
     [ID]
    ,[Name]
    ...
```

Note that `CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)` is `\r\n` (carriage return plus newline, or <kbd>Return</kbd>) and `CHAR(9)` is `\t` (<kbd>Tab</kbd>).

Now customize the result for your needs.